# File server in container

Tags: microsoft-distributed-file-system, fileserver, windows-container

I can see there are some implemented Web, DB servers are able to run as a container, it occurred to me that why not be able to implement as a file server with a centralized storage (e.g. SAN)

Does anyone try this before, or any recommendation to me?

My basic idea is use 2-3 docker images to create the file servers (mostly Windows servers) and they are mounting on the same storage. For the front-end, I may go or DFS namespaces to normalize the UNC path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows based images have `Server` service disabled out of the box. It's impossible to start it either since drivers are removed as well. It will not be possible to do in Windows containers.